# Which Toolkit to develop Mac OSX/Windows Daemon service

Tags: python, scala, service, cross-platform, daemons

I need to develop a daemon service which also has presence in System Tray. The system tray icon allows users to customize/access some options through right click menu. It might open a window as well manage those options in a better way.

The app would mostly be communicating with a RESTful service, posting and downloading files.

Now I know that for any daemon service, it needs to be native. However we don't have the luxury to maintain 3 different dev pipelines, specially since the app is experimental(but might land up in hands of users)

I have experience in Java/Scala, followed by C++/Python/JS. I would prefer java/Scala (existing codebase) but open to frameworks in other languages.

I was thinking of doing a scala based app with swing for windowing, but it is not pretty.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an App, same base code, running on Windows, OSX and Linux (with system tray) using these two set of components:

- The [Tanuki Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) to handle the lifecycle of the app. It also allows installing the component as a "native" windows service. Version 3.2.3 is under LGPL if that helps.
- The Java 6 [java.awt.SystemTray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html) which is supported on most platforms. On OSX, we use a modified version of [macify](http://simplericity.com/2007/10/02/1191336060000.html) to implement OSX specific gimmicks like doc icons

Answer (score 0):

You could go with JavaFX and the [ScalaFX](https://code.google.com/p/scalafx/) bindings. They look to be very actively maintained, and the syntax seems pretty clean. Only trouble is that it seems to have poor support for using the system tray - see [this discussion](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9994963) for details and some workarounds.

Comment: Is java FX 2 available on Mac? Can't really ask people install java 7 on mac.

Comment: Looks like it - (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/installation_2-2-7/jfxpub-installation_2-2-7.htm). Why can't they install Java 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Real Studio](http://www.realsoftware.com) to create a Windows Service and OS X/Linux daemons. Real Studio creates native apps for Windows, OS X and Linux.